# Why does this current not match my multimeter?

Tags: arduino, resistance, ohms-law

Newbie to electronics here! I have an Arduino Uno with a 15 Ω resistor connected to the 3.3 V pin, on my multimeter, it gives me 3.2 volts.

If I use this calculator:

https://ohmslawcalculator.com/ohms-law-calculator

And place values of 3.2 volts, and 15 Ω resistance, it tells me that it should be a current of 213 approx.

But when I test this with my multimeter, I get a current of 161ma approx.

Could anyone please explain why this happening, and what I am not calculating correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the burden voltage of your multimeter?

Comment: You now need a second multimeter, to read the resistance of the first one (and its test leads) on the mA range... I'll guess about 1 ohm (to read 200mV at 200mA) and about 0.5 ohms for the test leads. Factor that into your calculation.

Comment: Depends on the multimeter and how are you using it and in which mode, but the multimeter could really have about 5 ohms in it for current measuring so the added resistance will drop current.

Comment: Which multimeter, and what current range was it on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The impedance of your multimeter will be a few ohms. Add that to 15 Ω and if it's approximately 5 ohms, the circuit current will be 161 mA. In other words. 3.2 volts / 20 Ω = 160 mA.

Comment: Thanks Andy. That makes sense with the extra resistance of the multimeter itself.

Answer (score 7):

The 3.3 V of an [Arduino UNO](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-smd-schematic.pdf) comes out of an [LP2985](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp2985.pdf) voltage regulator. That thing isn't meant to source more than 150 mA; you're plain overloading it, with the expected result of the voltage dropping.

Comment: Sorry Marcus, this doesn't make sense to me? If I put just a wire in the 3.3v pin, and a wire in ground pin, and then read the current, it gives me about 300ma?

Comment: that's the so-called short circuit current. If you could measure the output voltage at that point, it would be very close to 0V. You draw more than half of that current, which is more than what the chip guarantees he can do at a 3.3V output voltage.

Comment: @JamesHatton PayBoth Andy's answer AND Marcus's answer tell you something of what is happening and there is more useful material here than is at first obvious. How much each affects the result depends on actual parameters involved. While Andy's answer may appear to provide a sole solution and MAY be the main factor, this is not certain with what you know so far. 
Using a second meter to measure several things would be valuable.eg what is the port voltage in each case? What is the meter voltage in each case? What is the meter resistance? Can you reconcile these various readings.

Comment: In that case the voltage over the resistor would not be 3.2V any more, but only 15 Ohm * 160mA = 2.4V. So I guess the LP2985 does deliver more current that specified.

Comment: @jusaca there's a short-circuit current graph in the datasheet (Fig. 6) that you'd want to compare to.

Answer (score 2):

Andy's answer AND Marcus's answer tell you something of what is happening and there is more useful material here than is at first obvious.

Factors include:

- Meter resistance
- Port voltage drop with current variation
- Voltage regulator voltage with current.

How much each affects the result depends on actual parameters involved.
While Andy's answer may appear to provide a sole solution and MAY be the main factor, this is not certain with what you know so far.

Using a second meter to measure several things would be valuable.
eg what is the port voltage in each case?
What is the meter voltage in each case?
What is the meter resistance?

Can you reconcile these various readings?

You could use a few resistors directly to ground & in series with the meter to load the port in various ways. Even with a single meter you could learn much. Using two meters makes it easier.

I long ago had a meter whose 200 mA range had such a high series resistance that it was vastly inaccurate on many measurements because of the degree to which it altered the actual current when placed "in circuit".